# How to conduct a posthoc test on effect size from linear mixed effect model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I have a linear mixed effect model with the following output

```
library(nlme)
library(readr)
data = read_csv("data/data/data.csv")
reg <- lme(independent ~ V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8,random = ~1+V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8|regions, data = data, control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: pre.sc 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  600.6398 845.2416 -245.3199

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 + V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8| regions
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr                                                   
(Intercept) 1.6577329  (Intr) V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7    
V1          0.7571502  0.540                                                 
V2          0.8005367  0.178 -0.528                                          
V3          0.1797059  0.458 -0.026 -0.189                                   
V4          0.2446572 -0.798  0.069 -0.607 -0.507                            
V5          0.5670119  0.067 -0.130 -0.101  0.593 -0.085                     
V6          0.3398192 -0.296 -0.278 -0.461  0.413  0.134 -0.060              
V7          0.2130404  0.702  0.665  0.276 -0.275 -0.378 -0.226 -0.766       
V8          0.5108382  0.197 -0.045 -0.239  0.499 -0.301 -0.348  0.785 -0.351
Residual    0.2866001                                                        

Fixed effects:  independent ~ V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8
                 Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.7766053 0.4291512 616  1.809631  0.0708
V1           0.1645515 0.2081782 616  0.790436  0.4296
V2           0.3866488 0.2145174 616  1.802412  0.0720
V3          -0.1674339 0.0628662 616 -2.663338  0.0079
V4           0.0602443 0.0707983 616  0.850928  0.3951
V5           0.3410149 0.1660426 616  2.053780  0.0404
V6          -0.6013393 0.0977449 616 -6.152131  0.0000
V7           0.5011307 0.0641320 616  7.814053  0.0000
V8          -0.2215405 0.1462669 616 -1.514632  0.1304
```

I perform an ANOVA anova

```
anova(reg)
            numDF denDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1   616  6.29290  0.0124
V1              1   616 19.42668  <.0001
V2              1   616 61.80804  <.0001
V3              1   616 37.51806  <.0001
V4              1   616 58.99058  <.0001
V5              1   616 27.74276  <.0001
V6              1   616  7.39450  0.0067
V7              1   616 59.34851  <.0001
V8              1   616  2.29411  0.1304
```

When I then perform a post hoc test with `emmeans` I get the following:

```
emmeans(x, list(pairwise ~ V7), adjust = "tukey")
$`emmeans of V7`
        V7 emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 -5.09e-15  0.777 0.429 15   -0.138     1.69

Degrees-of-freedom method: containment 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$` of V7`
 1         estimate SE df z.ratio p.value
 (nothing)   nonEst NA NA      NA      NA

Degrees-of-freedom method: containment
```

Why do I get that?

I would like to get something like:

```
$emmeans
time.point  emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
Region1        160 3.08  5      151      169
Region2        225 3.08  5      216      234
Region3        270 3.08  5      262      279
Region4        319 3.08  5      310      327
Region5        556 3.08  5      547      569     

Degrees-of-freedom method: containment 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
 
$contrasts
contrast           estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
Region1 - Region2     -65.0 4.39 12 -19.159 <.0001 
Region1 - Region3    -110.4 4.39 12 -32.541 <.0001 
Region1 - Region4    -158.8 4.39 12 -46.807 <.0001 
Region1 - Region5     -45.4 4.39 12 -13.382 <.0001 
Region2 - Region3     -93.8 4.39 12 -27.648 <.0001 
Region2 - Region4     -48.4 4.39 12 -14.266 <.0001
...
...
Region4 - Region5     -18.4 4.39 12 -21.266 <.0001
```

Why can I not get that from my model using a pairwise post hoc test?

Comment: because V7 is not a factor, it is a covariate. So it gets reduced to a single value, its average.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible (though, as I will explain later, unnecessary) to use `emmeans()` or similar *post hoc* analysis to obtain an estimate of the effect of `V7`. What you need to do is note that `V7` is a quantitative predictor (or covariate), rather than a factor, and as is documented, covariates are by default reduced to their mean. That is why in your output you see a single value of `V7` of $-5.09\times10^{-15}$, and why you can't do pairwise comparisons of a single estimate.

If you want a pairwise comparison, just specify two values for `V7`, then they can be compared. For example,

```
emmeans(x, list(pairwise ~ V7), at = list(V7 = c(0,1)), adjust = "tukey")
```

(note it is `"tukey"` not `"turkey"`)
I know exactly what the results will be: You will obtain an estimated pairwise comparison of -0.501 with an SE of 0.0641 and a $t$ ratio of  -7.814. I know this because we have specified a one-unit change in the value of `V7`, and the regression coefficient of `V7` is the slope of the `V7` trend, which is equal to the change in predicted value per unit change in `V7`. The sign is reversed because we are subtracting the second estimate from the first. If you had used `revpairwise` rather than `pairwise`, the sign would not change.

The bottom line, though, is that you *already have* an estimate of the effect of `V7`, precisely because `V7` is quantitative and thus its regression coefficient measures its marginal effect. You also already have estimates of the marginal effects of `V1` through `V6` and of `V8`.

And by the way, the Tukey adjustment is also completely unnecessary here (and will be ignored) because you have only one comparison that explains the entire effect of `V7` -- hence no multiple-testing issue.

Comment: I will add that it looks from the question like you want comparisons of regions. However, `region` does not appear in the fixed-effects part of the model, and `emmeans` works only with the fixed effects. If you want to compare regions, then that factor needs to be in the fixed-effect part, and you should specify `region`, not `V7`, in the `emmeans` call.